# i want to optimize this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have the following tables :

```
dbo.Details
Name     Type  SubType  SerialNumber  
D_01     TxA    STxA1     4            
D_02     TxB    STxB2     3            
D_03     TxC    STxC1     2            
D_04     TxD    STxD1     7           
D_05     TxD    STxD1     1            
D_06     TxD    STxD1     9            

dbo.DetailsType
Code Name
TxA   A
TxB   B
TxC   C
...

dbo.DetailsSubType
Code    Type    Name  CustomOR
STxA1   TxA     A1      1
STxA2   TxA     A2      0
STxB1   TxB     B1      1
STxB2   TxB     B2      0
STxC1   TxC     C1      1
STxC2   TxC     C2      0
STxD    TxD     D1      1
```

I want to know  what query (A or B)  is optimal in your opinion, with explanation please:

**QUERY A**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XXX
(
    @type nvarchar(10),
    @subType nvarchar(10) = null
)
AS
BEGIN 
declare @custom bit  = 0;
if (@subType is not null)
begin
    select @custom = CustomOR from dbo.DetailsSubType where SubType = @subType
end


select 
    DTST.SubType,
    DT.SerialNumber
from dbo.Details as  DT
left join DetailsSubType as DTST
    on DT.SubType = DTST.Code
where 
    DT.Type = @type
    and
    (
      @subType is null or
      (@custom = 0 and DTST.CustomOR= 0) or 
      (@custom = 1 and DT.SubType = @subType)
    )
END
```

**QUERY B**

```
   declare @custom bit  = 0;
if (@subType is not null)
begin
    select @custom = CustomOR from dbo.DetailsSubType where SubType = @subType
end
if (@custom = 0)
begin
        select 
            DTST.SubType,
            DT.SerialNumber
        from dbo.Details as  DT
        left join DetailsSubType as DTST
            on DT.SubType = DTST.Code
        where 
            DT.Type = @type
            and
            DTST.CustomOR = 0
end
else
begin
        select 
            DTST.SubType,
            DT.SerialNumber
        from dbo.Details as  DT
        left join DetailsSubType as DTST
            on DT.SubType = DTST.Code
        where 
            DT.Type = @type
            and
            (DTST.CustomOR = 1 and DT.SubType = @subType)
end
```

Comment: This question would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: dbo.DetailsSubType has no SubType. can you explain what are you trying to achieve please ? ex when @subtype is null  then DetailsSubType.customOR must be = 0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, *neither* may be optimal.  I am guessing that your concern is related to performance and the execution plan of the query.  The second method definitely gives SQL Server better opportunities for the optimization plan -- simply because `OR` is really hard to optimize.

But this doesn't take into account "parameter sniffing".  There are lots of articles about this subject ([here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) is a reasonable one).

Parameter sniffing means that SQL Server compiles the query the first time the stored procedure is called.  This saves the overhead of recompiling the queries -- a savings that is important if you have lots of "small" queries.  But a fool's bargain for larger queries -- because it does not take statistics on the table into account.

I would suggest that you look into articles about this.  You may find that the second solution is sufficient.  You may find that simply adding `option recompile` is sufficient.  You may find that you want to construct the query as dynamic SQL -- hey, you *know* it will be recompiled anyway.  But you'll be able to make a more informed decision.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing three queries that partition your results, where each query handles exactly one of your OR predicates, and UNION ALL the results.

In pseudo code:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE @subType is null
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE @subType is NOT null AND DTST.CustomOR = 0 AND @custom = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE @subType is NOT null AND DT.SubType = @subType AND @custom = 1
```

Having said that, what I actually think is that you should change your data model. It is extremely had (and very slow) to move forward with this setup. You probably haven't normalized your database properly.